# is there an j2me phone state listener similar to android's PhoneStateListener

Tags: java-me, gsm

I'm going to develop app that will need to **detect the caller number** and be able to **drop the call**. I've got several various j2ee midp2 enabled phones I want to use for this, but I can't find j2me API that is able to provide me the caller number and/or manage the call state (drop it).

On Android there is [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html), so app can listen to incoming calls and deals with it.

Since the application is not for resale / distribution (I am not bound to mobile phones but only to the GSM network) I can use also some reasonably priced industrial-grade solution too.

So the Q is: is there any possibility to detect caller details in j2me or I just have to trash all my available Nokia phones and buy some low-end Android stuff instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently, *low-end Android stuff* seems like the way to go.

- There is JavaME API specification for stuff like that ([JSR 253 Mobile Telephony](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=253)) but I am not aware of any real phones that support it

> The Mobile Telephony API allows java applications to access
>   call-related functionality such as:
>
> - Initiate voice and emergency calls
> - Receive/accept an incoming call
> - Control and end an existing call
> - Receive event notifications of call state changes
> - Receive event notifications of network state changes (e.g. roaming
>     to a different network)
> - Access network information such as Network ID and "Network Selection
>     Modes"
> - Use supplementary services such as multiparty calls, and call
>     forwarding
> - Get status information about supplementary services
> - Activate/deactivate supplementary services
> - Send/receive Unstructured Supplementary Service Data
> - Manage call-related phone and user parameters such as "Phone
>     Identity Presentation Restriction" or "User Group"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this functionality is not available in Java ME. Only you can make call from within an application. You can't access call registry.